# XMLHttpRequest run returned code

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Hey Guys I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` to get some content from another domain. 
`XMLHttpRequest` return gives me the whole Html file,  but i cant run the JS code inside the returned file. I can't use JQuery `$.get` so maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Why do you want to run the JS code that is embedded into an other page? What are you trying to do? What is your problem?

Comment: Do you have the right CORS headers going back & forth?

Comment: I am trying to initialize the google map into the new page. My Problem is that the code between <script></script> can't be executed. Even if i just say alert("test"); there is no response. I am going to load the page synchron so it's completely finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer for this , i found this statement on the documenattion

> Scripts in the resulting document tree will not be executed, resources referenced will not be loaded and no associated XSLT will be applied.